# Чтение файлов .rcp, .rcs от autodesk ReCap

Tags: sdk, autocad, cad

Требуется написать программу, которая берет файлы .rcp, .rcs и вытаскивает оттуда точки и прочие данные. Я знаю, что есть способ это сделать с использованием ReCap SDK, но эта штука доступна по платной подписке. Можно ли для этого использовать что-то другое? Например, ObjectARX?